# keyframes does not work when i use time remapping. How can it get fixed.?

Tags: animation, keyframes

When i start a project with blender, i can set key frames.but when it goes a little more complex, i doesn't work. I made a screen capture to show my problem in this link.
https://we.tl/t-jFhgm3FTB0
I tried lots of tutorial solution. but i can't make it work right.[image]

Comment: maybe share your file (just the camera)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots it's about 400mb. and it takes so long. did you watch the capture i've linked?

Comment: @moonboots I've found the problem. it's because of the Time Remapping option. What shoud i do before or after rempping to make Key frames works correctly?

Comment: in that case are you sure you want to remap?

Comment: @moonboots yes . its too fast.

Comment: so maybe the solution is simply to move the second keyframe, bring it back to the left?

Comment: @moonboots I tried but think it doesn't work this way. Every thing should set on 100/100 time remapping, then it can be extended.